# Greedy algorithm not functioning properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

This code is supposed to give me the least amount of coins (quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies) that add up to the amount owed.
when I enter values that are multiples of 0.25, it works seamlessly. But when I enter other values in the terminal, it just inserts a new line without doing anything. how did I mess up?

```
owed = float(input("how much change is owed?"))
coins = 0

if owed % 0.25 == 0:
    coins = owed / 0.25
    print(int(coins))
    exit()
elif owed % 0.25 != 0:
    while owed > 0:
        if (owed - 0.25) >= 0:
            coins += 1
            owed -= 0.25
        elif (owed - 0.10) >= 0:
            coins += 1
            owed -= 0.10
        elif (owed - 0.05) >= 0:
            coins += 1
            owed -= 0.05
        elif (owed - 0.01) >= 0:
            coins += 1
            owed -= 0.01
    print(int(coins))
    exit()
```

Comment: Both answers below suggest keeping `float` to get the input (GrandPhuba's only uses it once at least).  In general I would recommend going directly to int, if you need to, do `"".split('.')` and multiply the dollars by 100 to get cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is running infinite `while` loop due to some roundoff errors related to Float values caused by the internal representation of floating point numbers. So to fix these errors, we can use `round()` function to roundoff the value `owed` at the end of each `while` loop iteration:

```
elif owed % 0.25 != 0:
    while owed > 0:
        if (owed - 0.25) >= 0:
            coins += 1
            owed -= 0.25
        elif (owed - 0.10) >= 0:
            coins += 1
            owed -= 0.10
        elif (owed - 0.05) >= 0:
            coins += 1
            owed -= 0.05
        elif (owed - 0.01) >= 0:
            coins += 1
            owed -= 0.01
        owed = round(owed, 3) # In this line, we roundoff the value of owed
    print(int(coins))
    exit()
```

and this works fine.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Your program is stuck in the `while` loop due to floating-point errors. Try adding the following code just inside the `while` loop, and you will see that while `owed` does become infinitely small, it never becomes zero:

```
...
while owed > 0:
    print(owed)
    ...
```

Output:

```
...
8.326672684688674e-17
8.326672684688674e-17
8.326672684688674e-17
8.326672684688674e-17
...
```

Consider multiplying the input by `100` then deal with it as integers:

```
owed = int(float(input("How much change is owed? $")) * 100)

quarters = int(owed / 25)
dimes = int((owed - quarters * 25) / 10)
nickels = int((owed - quarters * 25 - dimes * 10) / 5)
cents = int((owed - quarters * 25 - dimes * 10 - nickels * 5))

coins = (quarters + dimes + nickels + cents)

print('Quarters (${}): {}'.format(quarters*0.25, quarters))
print('Dimes (${}): {}'.format(dimes*0.1, dimes))
print('Nickels (${}): {}'.format(nickels*0.05, nickels))
print('Cents (${}): {}'.format(cents, cents))
print('Coins:', coins)
```

Or if you want to stick with the greedy algorithm:

```
owed = int(float(input("How much change is owed? $")) * 100)

while owed > 0:
    if (owed - 25) >= 0:
        coins += 1
        owed -= 25
    elif (owed - 10) >= 0:
        coins += 1
        owed -= 10
    elif (owed - 5) >= 0:
        coins += 1
        owed -= 5
    elif (owed - 1) >= 0:
        coins += 1
        owed -= 1

coins = (quarters + dimes + nickels + cents)

print('Quarters (${}): {}'.format(quarters*0.25, quarters))
print('Dimes (${}): {}'.format(dimes*0.1, dimes))
print('Nickels (${}): {}'.format(nickels*0.05, nickels))
print('Cents (${}): {}'.format(cents, cents))
print('Coins:', coins)
```

Output

```
>>> How much change is owed? $1.42
Quarters ($1.25): 5
Dimes ($0.1): 1
Nickels ($0.05): 1
Cents ($2): 2
Coins: 9
```

For more information about floating point limitations, check the following: https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: thanks a lot man, I rounded the number to 3 places and that solved it. Also, that documentation is for Python 2.

Comment: @NourHabra  you're right, updated the link, though the idea stays the same. Note that rounding floats is usually not the best way of handling this problem, as while rounding does keep you from having an infinite loop, it simply masks the internal errors, which makes your program susceptible to certain corner cases